# Unable to access the value of radioButton when created inside a shiny server module

Tags: r, shiny, module, namespaces, radio-button

My shinyapp is build using modules, the radioBox component `inputId = modelling_type` is created in the server, using a renderUI function and stored under `outputId = modelling_type_ui`

As I'm using modules, I have name spaced my IDs in the `mod_ui`, and then in order to (attempt!) to use the same name space function in the `mod_server` I have called it via `ns <- parentsession$ns`. This doesn't throw an error. But I would now expect to  access the value of the RadioBox via `input$modelling_type`

This isn't working! So I must be calling the value incorrectly.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

# modules ------------------------------------------

mod_ui <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("modelling_type_ui")),
    
    textOutput(outputId = ns("capture"))
    
  )
  
}

mod_server <- function(id, parentsession){
  
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, server){
                 
                 ns <- parentsession$ns
                 
                 output$modelling_type_ui = renderUI({
                   
                   print(input$modelling_type) # this should not be null
                   
                   radioButtons(
                     inputId = ns("modelling_type"), 
                     label = "Choose a modelling technique",
                     choices = c("OLS",
                                 "Bayesian"),
                     selected = "OLS")
                   
                 })
               
                 output$capture = renderText({ paste0("modelling type selected:", input$modelling_type) })
                 
                 })
  
  }


# call app ---------------------------------------

# run app
ui <- function(){ mod_ui("mt") }
server <- function(input, output, session){ mod_server("mt", session) }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help appreciated. Usually I would just call radioButtons in the UI, and use updateradioButtons function in the server, but I'm dealing with a legacy app which uses the below method repeatedly.

Comment: The easiest way to get access to the value of the radio button in the module would be to get the module server to return its value to the application server function.  At the moment your module server has no return value.  Can you modify the module server code?  If so, that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, here is a MWE that I believe does what you want.

I'm not sure why you're using `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.  I assume it's needed in your actual use case, but it's not needed here.  Also, there's no need to muck about with `parentsession` and the like.

One reason why your debug print prints `NULL` is that you haven't defined the radio group at the time you try to print its value.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("modelling_type_ui")),
    textOutput(outputId = ns("capture"))
  )
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      ns <- session$ns
      
      output$modelling_type_ui = renderUI({
        radioButtons(
          inputId = ns("modelling_type"),
          label = "Choose a modelling technique",
          choices = c("OLS","Bayesian"), 
          selected = "OLS"
        )
      })
                 
      output$capture <- renderText({
        paste0("modelling type selected: ", input$modelling_type)
      })
  
      rv <- reactive({
        input$modelling_type
      })

      return(rv)
    }
  )
}

ui <- function() { 
  fluidPage(
    mod_ui("mt"),
    textOutput("returnValue")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  modValue <- mod_server("mt") 
  
  output$returnValue <- renderText({
    paste0("The value returned by the module is ", modValue())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem, as well as showing me how to access the value of radioButtons both inside and outside of the module. I realise now, I had not specified this in the question!

I made two mistakes - my moduleServer function should take the argument `session` (not server). And then I needed to call `ns <- session$ns` to get the ns function from the session. This fixed my app!

I have also learnt how to access the value outside my module by returning it as a reactive val. Thank you @Limey.

Comment: Oh and my third mistake (crucial!) - calling the `print(input$modelling_type)` in the renderUI block. As you say, on the first execution it doesn't yet exist. Then when the app is running, it would cause the renderUI block to be rerun every time `input$modelling_type` is changed by the user, and so resets the radioButtons back to selected = "OLS".